# User searchs DB for record, if found and viewed, attempt to return shows 'webpage expired'

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post

So in my MVC Orchard application the user chooses a location from a DD & selects a date from a datepicker. Search then looks through the DB table and returns a list of results (if any). User can then use the 'View' button to view each record on screen. This all works fine, however if the user presses the 'back' button, after viewing the record I get the error:

```
Webpage has expired
```

I've looked through other examples of GET and POST in my code and I can see no diff. does anyone have any idea why this is happening, think it is something to do with the search, please see code below

```
  @model Project.ViewModels.SearchDeliveryRunsVM
@{
    Script.Require("ShapesBase");
    Layout.Title = T("Delivery Runs History").ToString();
    Script.Require("jQuery");
    Script.Require("jQueryUI");
    Style.Require("jQueryUI_DatePicker");
}

@using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost())
{
        <div>
            <div style="display:inline-block">
                <div class="editor-label">Delivery Run</div>
                <div class="editor-label">@Html.DropDownList("DeliveryRunId", Model.DeliveryRunList)</div>
            </div>

            <div style="display:inline-block">
                <div class="editor-label">@T("Date")</div>
                <div class="editor-label">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SelectedDate, new { @class = "jquery_datepicker", @Value = Model.SelectedDate.HasValue ? Model.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : string.Empty })</div>
            </div>

            <button style="display:inline-block" type="submit">@T("Search")</button>
        </div>  
    if (Model.Orders != null && Model.Orders.Count() > 0)
    {  

    <br />
        <table class="items">
            <colgroup>
                <col id="Col10" />
                <col id="Col11" />
            </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <th>Order Id</th>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Value</th>
            <th>Payment</th>
            <th>Signature</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

            @foreach (Project.Models.OrderInfo results in Model.Orders)
            {
             <tr>
                <td>@results.OrderRecordId</td>
                <td>@results.QbCustName</td>
                <td>@results.Value</td>
                <td>@results.Payment</td>
                <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => results.Signature, new { disabled = "disabled" })</td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                            <a href="@Url.Action("ViewOrder", "DeliveryRuns", new { id = results.OrderRecordId, custId = results.QbCustId })" title="@T("ViewOrder")">@T("ViewOrder")</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
             </tr>
            }
        </table>
    }
    else
    { 
        if (!Model.IsInitialGet)
        {
            <p>No records exist</p>
        }
    }

}
    @using (Script.Foot())
    {
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(function () {
                var dates = $("#SelectedDate").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
                }).val("@(Model.SelectedDate.HasValue ? Model.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))");
            });
        </script>
    }
```

**UPDATE**
All the other search features on my site are using the Index function of each controller, then in the view using something like:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "CustomerAdmin", FormMethod.Get)) {
    <fieldset class="bulk-actions">
        <label for="search">@T("Search:")</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchExpression)
        <button type="submit">@T("Search")</button>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index")">@T("Clear")</a>
    </fieldset>
}
```

to use the GET to display the results, where as my problem I am using GET and POST. perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that a page created by a POST action expires after the page is navigated away from; you wouldn't, for example, want the back button to trigger a second credit card charge attempt... You could try using output caching